# How to determine when animation of Page Transition has ended?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using Windows Phone Toolkit - Feb 2011 (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) for Page Transitions.

Code for handling page transitions is in xaml. I want to run some methods after animation is completed.

So my question is: Is it possible to detect when transition animation is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an EndTransition event you can hook up to on toolkit:NavigationInTransition

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition EndTransition="TransitionComplete">
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                    . . .
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how could I miss it.